# Getting a Controller, Route and Hidden-Field-Button to work correctly in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, controller

I would like to create a button so that a user can enroll in a course. The enrolling model belongs_to users and courses and should keep track of enrollment.

I have the following code displayed as a button-form on a course page (looks fine):

```
<% @enroll = current_user.enrollings.build(course_id: @course.id) %>
<%= form_for(@enroll) do |f| %>  
    <div><%= f.hidden_field :course_id %></div>
    <%= f.submit "Enroll", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I have a resources route for enrollings, and when the user clicks on the button, the page goes to /enrollings.

This is the code in the enrolling controller:

```
def create    
@course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
current_user.enroll!(@course)
end
```

When I click on the button, I get the following error message:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in EnrollingsController#create
>
> Couldn't find Course without an ID

Why isn't it passing the course_id with the form? How do I setup the controller correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<div><%= hidden_field_tag "course_id", @course.id %></div>
```

Comment: That throws a no method error on that line: undefined method `merge' for 2:Fixnum

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have worked. Though I wonder how it could have been fixed without changing the form (just the controller).

Comment: Well, you couldn't because you weren't passing the value of course_id to the controller with `f.hidden_field :course_id`. All that this piece of code is doing is wait for it to be populated. =]